# How destroy specific user session when we are using default php session handler?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, session, permissions, super-user

If a user A and a user B are both super user and the user A removes the super user permission of the user B, and the user B is logged in, while the user B session remain active, he can do anything on the system including recover his super user permission.

**Update**

Looking at the `JUser::authorise` method, we can see something like this:

```
public function authorise($action, $assetname = null)
{
    // Make sure we only check for core.admin once during the run.
    if ($this->isRoot === null)
    {
        //check if the user is root
    }

    return $this->isRoot ? true : JAccess::check($this->id, $action, $assetname);
}
```

So, if the user get logged in as super user, the `JUser` object in the session will have the `isRoot` property as true and the `authorise` method will always return true without check the current permission in database.

**OBS**: `JFactory:getUser()` return the `JUser` in session

Comment: If I rightly remember, I tried something like this. I removed the super user permissions from user B whilst they were in the backend, then refresh the page and they were not able to access the backend.

Comment: what version did you try? In the version 3.3.1 I did the same test as you and the user B remains able to access the backend after refresh.

Comment: I think it was Joomla 2.5.22. I will have another test again later on and let you know. Will be sure to test 3.3.1 this time though

Comment: @Lodder Take a look at my edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho the only way would be to delete the session in the database (#__session table).

Then the user is forced to log in again and the permissions are calculated fresh.

**UPDATE:** As the comment below, there is no "joomla way" to destroy the session if we are using `JSessionStorageNone`. So, `you likely have to wait till that users session times out or he logs out himself`.

Comment: It works if we are using `JSessionStorageDatabase`. If we are using `JSessionStorageNone`, this wont force the user to log in again.

Comment: True. Then you likely have to wait till that users session times out or he logs out himself.